# Unable to Enable Night Light (Blue Light Filter) on External Monitor via Docking Station in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: displaylink, night-light

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 in conjunction with my Docking Station ICY BOX USB-C Docking Station (11-in-1) for 2 Monitors (2x DisplayPort), 4K 60Hz, 6-fach USB 3.0 HUB, Gigabit Ethernet, Audio, Schwarz, IB-DK2242AC, and the LG 35WN65C LCD-Monitor.

Currently, I have only one monitor connected to my docking station, and the docking station is connected to my laptop via USB-A. Everything works perfectly, except I can't enable the night light (blue light filter) on my external monitor. It does work with my laptop.

I have tried third-party apps like RedShift and Brightness Controller, but once again, the changes only affect my laptop and not my external monitor.

However, if I directly connect my monitor to my laptop, the night light feature works. Nevertheless, this means I need to have one monitor cable and one USB cable for the docking station. I want everything to go through the docking station.

If I log into Ubuntu with XORG and type 'xrandr,' I get the following output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 820mm x 346mm
   3440x1440     99.98*+  84.96    59.97    49.99  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```

I had the same problem with Windows 11. However, I managed to fix it by following this manual:
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1886413-how-to-enable-night-light-or-f-lux-on-displaylink

Unfortunately, DisplayLink does not have an official solution for Ubuntu, as mentioned by the support team when I emailed them.

Lastest Ubuntu and DisplayLink updates are installed.

Has anyone managed to get it working with Ubuntu?